How to add custom attributes to wordpress block theme
I am creating a wordpress theme wth html and jquery. I want to add a data attribute to my pattern so that I can use jquery to control the behaviour. When I add a data attribute to my code, I get an error that an invalid property has been added. How do I fix this without using a plugin?
My pattern:
<?php

/**
* Title: Resume Layout
* Slug: portfolia/resume-default
* Categories: featured
*/
?>

<!-- wp:group {"metadata":{"categories":["featured"],"patternName":"portfolia/resume-default","name":"Resume Layout"},"className":"portfolia-resume-layout","layout":{"type":"flex","flexWrap":"nowrap","justifyContent":"center","verticalAlignment":"top"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group portfolia-resume-layout">
<!-- wp:group {"className":"portfolia-sidebar"} -->
<div class="wp-block-group portfolia-sidebar">
 <!-- wp:buttons {"layout":{"type":"flex","orientation":"vertical"}} -->
 <div class="wp-block-buttons">
   <!-- wp:button {"backgroundColor":"black","textColor":"white","className":"portfolia-sidebar-item active","style":{"elements":{"link":{"color":{"text":"var:preset|color|white"}}}}} -->
   <div class="wp-block-button portfolia-sidebar-item active"><a
       class="wp-block-button__link has-white-color has-black-background-color has-text-color has-background has-link-color wp-element-button">
       Experience</a></div>
   <!-- /wp:button -->

   <!-- wp:button {"backgroundColor":"black","textColor":"white","className":"portfolia-sidebar-item","style":{"elements":{"link":{"color":{"text":"var:preset|color|white"}}}}} -->
   <div class="wp-block-button portfolia-sidebar-item"><a
       class="wp-block-button__link has-white-color has-black-background-color has-text-color has-background has-link-color wp-element-button">
       Skills</a></div>
   <!-- /wp:button -->

   <!-- wp:button {"backgroundColor":"black","textColor":"white","className":"portfolia-sidebar-item is-style-fill","style":{"elements":{"link":{"color":{"text":"var:preset|color|white"}}}}} -->
   <div class="wp-block-button portfolia-sidebar-item is-style-fill"><a
       class="wp-block-button__link has-white-color has-black-background-color has-text-color has-background has-link-color wp-element-button">
       Education</a></div>
   <!-- /wp:button -->

   <!-- wp:button {"backgroundColor":"black","textColor":"white","className":"portfolia-sidebar-item","style":{"elements":{"link":{"color":{"text":"var:preset|color|white"}}}}} -->
   <div class="wp-block-button portfolia-sidebar-item"><a
       class="wp-block-button__link has-white-color has-black-background-color has-text-color has-background has-link-color wp-element-button">
       Certifications</a></div>
   <!-- /wp:button -->
 </div>
 <!-- /wp:buttons -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->

<!-- wp:group {"className":"portfolia-main-content"} -->
<div class="wp-block-group portfolia-main-content">
 <!-- wp:group {"className":"portfolia-content-section active"} -->
 <div id="experience" class="wp-block-group portfolia-content-section active">
   <!-- wp:heading -->
   <h2 class="wp-block-heading">Experience</h2>
   <!-- /wp:heading -->

   <!-- wp:table {"hasFixedLayout":false,"className":"is-style-regular"} -->
   <figure class="wp-block-table is-style-regular">
     <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Title</th>
           <th>Company</th>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th>Date</th>
           <th>Location</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>DevOps Engineer</td>
           <td>Bitmama</td>
           <td>We conduct thorough evaluations of your competitors and</td>
           <td>Jan 2021 - Present</td>
           <td>Remote</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Customer Reliability Engineer (DevOps)</td>
           <td>Cloudkite.io</td>
           <td>We conduct thorough evaluations of your competitors and</td>
           <td>Jul 2020 – Jul 2022, Jan 2023 – Nov 2023</td>
           <td>Remote</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>DevOps Engineer</td>
           <td>Goodlight (Andela)</td>
           <td>We conduct thorough evaluations of your competitors and</td>
           <td>Aug 2019 - Mar 2020</td>
           <td>Remote</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Software Developer</td>
           <td>Andela Talent Accelerator</td>
           <td>We conduct thorough evaluations of your competitors and</td>
           <td>Dec 2018 - Mar 2020</td>
           <td>Lagos, Nigeria</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
   <!-- /wp:table -->
 </div>
 <!-- /wp:group -->

 <!-- wp:group {"className":"portfolia-content-section"} -->
 <div id="skills" class="wp-block-group portfolia-content-section">
   <!-- wp:heading -->
   <h2 class="wp-block-heading">Skills</h2>
   <!-- /wp:heading -->

   <!-- wp:table {"hasFixedLayout":false,"className":"is-style-regular"} -->
   <figure class="wp-block-table is-style-regular">
     <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Skill</th>
           <th>Level</th>
           <th>Years of Experience</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>DevOps</td>
           <td>Expert</td>
           <td>5+</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Cloud Computing</td>
           <td>Advanced</td>
           <td>4</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Containerization</td>
           <td>Advanced</td>
           <td>3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>CI/CD</td>
           <td>Expert</td>
           <td>5</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Infrastructure as Code</td>
           <td>Advanced</td>
           <td>4</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
   <!-- /wp:table -->
 </div>
 <!-- /wp:group -->

 <!-- wp:group {"className":"portfolia-content-section"} -->
 <div id="education" class="wp-block-group portfolia-content-section">
   <!-- wp:heading -->
   <h2 class="wp-block-heading">Education</h2>
   <!-- /wp:heading -->

   <!-- wp:table {"hasFixedLayout":false,"className":"is-style-regular"} -->
   <figure class="wp-block-table is-style-regular">
     <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Degree</th>
           <th>School</th>
           <th>Date</th>
           <th>GPA</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>Master of Science in Cloud Computing</td>
           <td>Tech Institute</td>
           <td>2019 - 2021</td>
           <td>3.8</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Bachelor of Science in Computer Science</td>
           <td>University of Technology</td>
           <td>2014 - 2018</td>
           <td>3.7</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
   <!-- /wp:table -->
 </div>
 <!-- /wp:group -->

 <!-- wp:group {"className":"portfolia-content-section"} -->
 <div id="certifications" class="wp-block-group portfolia-content-section">
   <!-- wp:heading -->
   <h2 class="wp-block-heading">Certifications</h2>
   <!-- /wp:heading -->

   <!-- wp:table {"hasFixedLayout":false,"className":"is-style-regular"} -->
   <figure class="wp-block-table is-style-regular">
     <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Certification</th>
           <th>Date</th>
           <th>Expiry</th>
           <th>Credential ID</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>AWS Certified DevOps Engineer - Professional</td>
           <td>2022</td>
           <td>2025</td>
           <td>AWS-DEP-123456</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Google Cloud Professional DevOps Engineer</td>
           <td>2021</td>
           <td>2024</td>
           <td>GCP-DEP-789012</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Certified Kubernetes Administrator (CKA)</td>
           <td>2020</td>
           <td>2023</td>
           <td>CKA-345678</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
   <!-- /wp:table -->
 </div>
 <!-- /wp:group -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->

My Jquery code:
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".portfolia-content-section").hide();
  $(".portfolia-content-section.active").show();

  $(".portfolia-sidebar-item").click(function () {
    $(".portfolia-sidebar-item").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    const tabId = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "_");

    // Use console.log to check what tabId is generated
    console.log("Tab ID:", tabId);

    $(".portfolia-content-section").hide();
    $("#" + tabId).show();
  });
});


I'm not seeing the data attribute in your HTML, or in your jQuery code, can you update your question so that we can replicate the issue and see what you attempted?

Sorry, in the cause of debugging, I removed the tag. But this issue is resolved. I ended up adding classes to the tab buttons, and using jquery to extract the classes and use them as a reference.
